# question disappearing from my filter

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, tag-filters

I posted this a few days ago and then deleted, because I thought I was seeing things wrong, but I'm not, so here goes again:

I have a filter set up for all my favourite tags. It is in my bookmarks. I open the page and refresh it frequently by clicking the Filtered Questions link in my  filters page.

I see a question that has been asked a few minutes ago, open it on a new tab, answer it, close the tab and I'm back on the filter page.

I refresh the filter page by clicking the Filtered Questions link. Sometimes, not always, I now see much older questions at the top of the filter and the Q I just answered is no longer visible.

I've seen questions about disappearing questions, but they were about differences between pages and there was caching involved.

Whereas I am looking at the same page, refreshing the same filter that I was using before. It happened again just a few minutes ago. My "FavTags" filter, where I saw the question "Excel Formula Flag Triggering", asked 20 mins ago, now shows the newest question as 5 mins ago, the next one as 1 hr ago and nothing in between.

If I change to the "Favourite Tags" filter, I see the same newest question at the top, and the next ones asked 9, 11, 20 (the one I answered), 34 mins ago.

This happens intermittently. If this is due to caching, how come I'm being served an older cache while staying on the same page? And how come that a very new question shows up on the filter, but there is a gap to the next newest question?

Forcing a full browser refresh with Ctrl / Shift / F5 etc. does not resolve the issue.

Screenshot of the "Favourite Tags" filter with all questions showing:
[image]

Screenshot of my personal "FavTags" filter with questions missing between the first and second. Look at the time stamps. Note that the screenshot above was taken even a few seconds later than this one, because the clock in had already rolled over to 6 minutes ago, whereas below it still shows 5 minutes ago.

[image]

Eventually, my FavTags filter will show the question again, and more questions that have been asked in the mean time and that I did not see when refreshing the page earlier.

I think this is a bug.

Comment: Yeah, cache is working in weird ways sometimes. With so many things cached in so many different places, it's not surprising to get such bugs - hopefully, the team will take a look and maybe fix this soon.